# Rails 4 and MailChimp: Cannot get First Name and Last Name to merge on sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp

I am trying to create a subscription for MailChimp when users sign up on my website. I have successfully added them to my "Newsletter" list by email but their first name and last name do not show up. I have referred to the following:

[Aspiring Web Dev: Guide](http://aspiringwebdev.com/e-mail-in-rails-with-mailchimp-and-mandrill-a-comprehensive-guide/#Subscribe_users_to_your_MailChimp_list)

[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby)

[MailChimp API Docs](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/)

[RubyDoc - mailchimp-api gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp-api/2.0.4/Mailchimp/Lists#subscribe-instance_method)

In the User model, I've tried:

**user.rb**

```
after_create :add_newsletter_subscriber

def add_newsletter_subscriber
 mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
 mailchimp.lists.subscribe(ENV['NEWSLETTER-LIST-ID'], {
    :email => self.email,       
     :merge_vars => {
                      "FNAME" => self.first_name,
                      "LNAME" => self.last_name
                    },
      :double_optin => false
 })
end
```

...

```
def add_newsletter_subscriber
 mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
 mailchimp.lists.subscribe(ENV['NEWSLETTER-LIST-ID'], {
    :email => self.email,       
     :merge_vars => {
                      :FNAME => self.first_name,
                      :LNAME => self.last_name
                    },
      :double_optin => false
 })
end
```

...

```
def add_newsletter_subscriber
 mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
 mailchimp.lists.subscribe(ENV['NEWSLETTER-LIST-ID'], {
    :email => self.email,       
     :merge_vars => {
                      "FIRSTNAME" => self.first_name,
                      "LASTNAME" => self.last_name
                    },
      :double_optin => false
  })
 end
```

...

```
def add_newsletter_subscriber
 mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
 mailchimp.lists.subscribe(ENV['NEWSLETTER-LIST-ID'], {
    :email => self.email,       
     :merge_vars => {
                      "FNAME" => :first_name,
                      "LNAME" => :last_name
                    },
      :double_optin => false
  })
 end
```

...

```
def add_newsletter_subscriber
 mailchimp = Mailchimp::API.new(ENV['MAILCHIMP-API-KEY'])
 mailchimp.lists.subscribe(ENV['NEWSLETTER-LIST-ID'], {
    :email => self.email,       
     :merge_vars => {
                      "*|FNAME|*" => self.first_name,
                      "*|LNAME|* => self.last_name
                    },
      :double_optin => false
 })
end
```

All of these send the email to MailChimp but not the first and last name. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [gibbon gem](https://github.com/amro/gibbon) to work with the latest (v3) API version.

`mailchimp-api-ruby` gem works only with deprecated v2 version.

Comment: Thanks @MikDiet ! I wasn't aware the [MailChimp API v3](https://github.com/Xenapto/mailchimp_api_v3) was a separate gem. I included the Gibbon Gem and pretty much followed [this tutorial](http://aspiringwebdev.com/e-mail-in-rails-with-mailchimp-and-mandrill-a-comprehensive-guide/).